# How to add send data from my database to a text area form in html

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, mysql

I have a profile page and one of the sections is an about me section that i created,  i resolved to create a table inside my datable called suggestions where i have lists of suggestions a user use for his about me section..I have managed to display the data from my table and the text area on my form side by side  but i want to a create a function where once i click on a particular suggestion, it will be transferred directly into my text area field for the user

*Edit
With the current code, Only the first suggestion when clicked on gets sent to the text area, Double clicking on the first suggestion again does nothing.
The outcome should have been that any of the suggestions when clicked on will get sent to the text area.

```
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title><?php if(isset($page_title)) echo $page_title; ?></title>
    
    <!--Bootstrap--->
     <link href="../img/faviconn.png" rel="icon">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
   <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
   
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="js/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sweetalert.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
  
    <link href="css/intlTelInput.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-tagsinput.css">
</head>


<table width="891" height="80" align="center" class="table table-condensed">
    <tr>
        <td width="50%" height="74">
            <div class="form-group" style="overflow-y:scroll; width: 100%;height: 400px;">
                <div class="form-group" align="center">
                    <h4 style="background-color:darkseagreen;color: whitesmoke;width: 190px;">Suggestions</h4>
                </div><br><br>
                <div class="row">
                    <table class="table">
                        

<tr>
                <?php
 
require_once('config/connect.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM aboutsug";
$res = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);


?></tr>
            <?php 
                while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $r['id']; ?></td>
                    <td style="padding:25px;" onclick="fillTextArea('<?php echo $r['suggest']; ?>')"><?php echo $r['suggest']; ?></td>
                
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="45%"> 
            <div class="form-group" style="height: 400px;">
                <div class="form-group" align="center">
                    <h4 style="background-color:darkseagreen;color: whitesmoke;width: 190px;">About Me</h4>
                </div>
                <textarea name="about" class="form-control" id="about" spellcheck="true" style="height: 400px;"></textarea>
            </div> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
     function fillTextArea(data){
         document.getElementById('about').value=data;
     }
 </script>
```

[image]

[image: Original before the changes]

Comment: show us some of your code and we will try to help you. what have you tried? and what went wrong? at least show the code snipet of your page.

Comment: Very sorry, i formatted the page the wrong way

Comment: Hi Abraham. Just a friendly suggestion. And i make this mistake too all the time :)
Concerning comments like "I tried using data-list for my text area but did not work". You should consider if that information is actually useful for the people helping with the issue. If it is useful, include more information to cover why its relevant. Otherwise, simply omit it. And have a nice day :)

Comment: @ Martin Nielsen Thank you

Comment: @Martin Nielsen , any solution to my problem?

Comment: @AbrahamAugustusNortey No sorry. I just ran into your question on the triage line.

Comment: Try avoiding questions like "how do I do this?", instead try to do it yourself and ask about any problems you encounter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: result of the first click][image: result of the second click] i just copied the question and it works on my system you must have been doing something wrong. For this purpose you can use javascript

1. in your `<td>` tag that contains the `$r['suggest']` set attribut `onclick="fillTextArea('<?php echo $r['suggest']; ?>')"`

change `<td style="padding:25px;"><?php echo $r['suggest']; ?></td>` to `<td style="padding:25px;" onclick="fillTextArea('<?php echo $r['suggest']; ?>')"><?php echo $r['suggest']; ?></td>`

2. go to the bottom of your document and add the following javascript code

   ```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fillTextArea(data){
            document.getElementById('about').value=data;
        }
    </script>
   ```

Comment: Tried it but this time didnt work.. the section could not echo data from the table.. Editing my original post and will upload an image of the issue

Comment: you want the `$r['suggest']` content to be in the textarea right?

Comment: what is the first blank photo is it with the new code?

Comment: Yes the first photo was blank after the new code and yes i want the $r['suggest'] to in the text area

Comment: PLease is there a way to fix it?

Comment: i have updated the answer let me know@AbrahamAugustusNortey

Comment: I tried it but when i click the suggestions nothing happens

Comment: So i took out the <?php if(isset($about)) echo $about; ?> i had in about textarea and  seems only the first results get added to the text area when clicked on whiles the rest does not.. As seen in the image above i have about 7 suggestions being displayed but only  the first one works

Comment: what happens when you click on the rest are they replacing the one that has been sent? if that is the case it's because the code is written to behave that way and we can fix that. anyway edit your question with your latest status and problems you are facing. @AbrahamAugustusNortey

Comment: did it work for you? if it did there is 2 thing to do kindly accept the answer and vote up. if it didn't explain the new issue you are facing.@AbrahamAugustusNortey

Comment: No sir it's not working as expected , only the first column get added when clicked on. So if they are 10 entries in my database, only the first entry when I click on is sent to the text area. The rest does not get sent to the text area like the first

Comment: It works on my system i have attached the result on my localhost. i just copied a code from the question. @AbrahamAugustusNortey

Comment: Please i updated my original post and included the header files am using, Please check it out for me if its related

Comment: try disabling all other javascript scripts and see if it works there might be a conflict some where comment out all `<script></script>` except the one we wrote. @AbrahamAugustusNortey

Comment: Just did that but still the problem is still there

Comment: let me host live site and share a link with you wait just a moment.

Comment: let me host live site and share a link with you wait just a moment.

Comment: Seen it sir but Please if i may ask are you using a table with the information in there where you have manually assigned "Onclick" attribute to all of them or is the information stored on a database?

Comment: no it is stored on database i happened to have access to that site database whoever hosted it.

Comment: now you see that it works feel free to accept and up vote the answer it will help someone.

Comment: Ok. I have checked every part of my code and cant trace why mine is not working , meanwhile I have confirmed that your code is worked and hence voted it as the answer . Am very grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Please also in relation to the working code is there a way to add multiple entries when clicked and not just once?

Comment: Yeah just make the JavaScript dance a bit.